# Js/Jquery - Сделать поиск/действие внутри переменной, почему не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не получается работать с содержимым внутри переменной.
Я беру html код из инпута, пытаюсь сделать реплейсы, и в довершение мне нужно удалить ссылки (атрибут href)....
Подскажите пожалуйста.

```js
$('#button').click(function() {

var b = $('#input').val(); // беру содержимое из инпута

b = b.replace(/<div class="tbody">/g,"<table class='results'>");
b = b.replace(/<div class="g-row container">/g,"");
b = b.replace(/<div class="g-row justify-sb">/g, "<tr>");// делаю пару реплейсов.

b.find('a').each(function(){
   $(this).removeAttr("href");
}); // ругается что b.find не функция.

$('#result').val(b);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" style="width: 600px; height: 200px;">
<button id='button' type="submit">Submit</button>
<BR><BR>
<input type="text" style="width: 600px; height: 200px;" id="result">
```

Comment: Текст свой добавьте в input

Comment: Так я и добавляю.
Вставляю например <a class="table-row" href="https://google.com">Link</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте так

```js
$('#button').click(function() {

var b = document.createElement('div');
b.innerHTML = $('#input').val();

$(b).find('a').each(function(){
   $(this).removeAttr("href");
}); // ругается что b.find не функция.

$('#result').val(b.innerHTML);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" style="width: 600px; height: 200px;">
<button id='button' type="submit">Submit</button>
<BR><BR>
<input type="text" style="width: 600px; height: 200px;" id="result">
```

Comment: У меня там стоят реплейсы, и теперь они не работают.
подправил код.


b = b.replace(/<div class="tbody">/g,"<table class='results'>");
b = b.replace(/<div class="g-row container">/g,"");
b = b.replace(/<div class="g-row justify-sb">/g, "<tr>");

Comment: Я показал лишь вам как надо сделать

Comment: Если ответ вам помог то можете пометить

Comment: Да, я дописал то что нужно было. Спасибо огромное. 
Ваше var b = document.createElement('div');
b.innerHTML = $('#input').val();
Просто то что надо!!!